# This app has not been updated to 64 bit. Using it may affect overall system performance

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cpu-architecture, ios10

Recently, when I try to update my iOS application, I receive this popup. Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

.[image]

Comment: You should… [update your app to 64-bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Do you want to support both 32 and 64 bit arch?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions in [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch: Converting Your App to a 64-Bit Binary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1) to target a 64-bit runtime environment.